# How can I delete the file?

Tags: java, android

The delete() doesn't work, because it does't delete file, and method exists returns false. Where is my mistake? There are problem code. Also I pasted all code on pastebin
Sorry for my English. All code is [here](https://pastebin.com/vz0yMCLv)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etText, etFileName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

private void openFile(String fileName) {}

private void saveFile(String fileName) {}

private void clear() {}

private void delete(String fileName) {
    try {
        Log.d("MYTAG", fileName);
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Log.d("MYTAG", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("MYTAG", Boolean.toString(file.exists()));
        file.delete();
        Log.d("MYTAG", Boolean.toString(file.exists()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Такого файла не существует!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.save:
            saveFile(etFileName.getText().toString() + ".txt");
            break;
        case R.id.open:
            openFile(etFileName.getText().toString() + ".txt");
            break;
        case R.id.del:
            delete(etFileName.getText().toString() + ".txt");
            break;
        case R.id.clear:
            clear();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you given permission to read and write for storage Please check and try again?

Comment: @Vijendrapatidar if you mean pastebin, I, unfortunately, won't be able. But i can paste my code to github. Will it be better for you?

Comment: Runtime marshmallow permission.

Comment: Which Android version you're running/testing on? Please add stack trace too.

Comment: @AshutoshKS Sorry, what do you mean under stack trace? My Android version? Or all logs?

Comment: What's your Android version? Also, add stack trace for this error (not all logs).

Comment: `Log.d("MYTAG", fileName);` What does it log? What is the value of `fileName`? You cannot just put a name there. And we do not know what is typed in that text view.

Comment: `and method exists returns false.` You call exists()) twice. Is it already false the first time? If yes, then why do you continue? Display a Toast() to inform the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file.getAbsoluteFile().delete()`, instead of `file.delete()` also check the returned boolen  to be sure the file has been deleted,
so, your delete function will be something like this

```java
private void delete(String fileName) {
   try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(!file.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(file.getAbsoluteFile().delete())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File couldn't be deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Такого файла не существует!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Also make sure your app has the write permission to external storage

check here for more info for permissions:[Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` Which file? Why not tell which file? `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n\nFile doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`